# how to get session values from one module to another in joomla

Tags: session, module, joomla2.5

Hi I have two module and passing users id with session from one module to second module, using following code.

// To set session with joomla (first module)

```
$getCompID = JRequest::getVar('compID');        
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('comID', $getCompID);
```

// To get session with joomla (second module)

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('comID');
```

i can't get session value in second module. 
plz help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is possibility that either you did not reload page in first module and try to set session and accessing session in second module.

so first try to reload same page in first module and assign session or You should use following code in your second module

`$getCompID = JRequest::getVar('compID');`

`$session =& JFactory::getSession();`

`$session->set('comID', $getCompID);`

`echo $session->get('comID');`

Pass your variable to 'compID' to second module and than try to set session over there